# Azure Pipelines moving one repo pipelines to multiple-repo pipelines. What is the minimal change needed?

Tags: azure-pipelines

we initially build our pipelines and templates based on the assumption that we will only check our own working repo. This works fine and we used $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to refer to the repo's root directory. However, now we are building a multi-repo pipeline and the repo's path becomes $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/repo-name. Then we have a conflict now. In multi-repo pipeline, our templates cannot refer to our repo anymore using $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). It seems like we must change every place we use this system variable to refer to our new repo's location. What's a better solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable like `workingdirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/repo-name`, then replace `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` used currently to `$(workingdirectory)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We have thought about this. The problem with this is that we then need to do a condition on every single place where we use working directory, since some pipelines are single-repo pipeline and some are multi-repo pipeline. They share the same set of templates. So the template cannot assume that $(workdingdirectory) takes a dependency on a repo's name.

Comment: How about adding a script task (`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=workingdirectory;]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/repo-name"` or `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=workingdirectory;]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"`) to define the variable `workingdirectory` dynamically?

Comment: How's your issue going? Is my reply helpful?